# How to make a textbox show me double?

Tags: c#, textbox, var

I am trying to get myself used to C#, currently I am using SharpDevelop for that Task, anyway, I have a simple question, let's say I want to have a TextBox that Shows me the outcome of a mathematical code as shown below, how do I get the TextBox to actually Show me types like double, int, or other stuff? It always tells me it can't convert double to string or whatever, I am pretty noob so yeah.

```
void CmdWriteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double var = 8.40;
        double start = 9.00;
        double end = var + start;
        textbox_end.Text = end;
    }
```

I already tried to not use the .text but something like. value but didn't work, any help?

Comment: In what way did it not work? Could you post the actual output or actual error message you are receiving?

Comment: So you want the data type to display, instead of the actual answer?

Comment: @RobertColumbia it says (roughly translated) "a conversion of type "double" in "string" is not possible. (CS0029)"

Comment: @JohnnyBones no, i want to Display the actual answer, but the answer is a "double" and it tells me that this conversion is not possible.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: arent they similar in many things? and as this is very Basic I thought you guys could help too ;), sry

Comment: C# has a lot more in common with Java than with C++. Just make sure you tag your language correctly or you'll probably get some downvotes from those trying to punish language tag spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `.ToString()`

```
textbox_end.Text = end.ToString()
```

Comment: I'd probably go with this one, actually.

Comment: this worked, do I have always to work like that with textboxes? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping it in a string, like:

```
void CmdWriteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double var = 8.40;
        double start = 9.00;
        double end = var + start;
        textbox_end.Text = "" + end + "";
    }
```